# Devbridge autocomplete ajax not working when bind database

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-core, autocomplete

I want to use [devbridge](https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/) autocomplete ajax in my project. This plugin must bind data from databse. In the following you can see my code :

**In View**

```
<input type="text" id="searchinput" name="searchinput" />
```

**Jquery**

```
    <script>
    $('#searchinput').autocomplete({
        serviceUrl: '/Controller/fetchCondidate',
        onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**In Controller**

```
    public IActionResult fetchCondidate()
    {
        var q = JsonConvert.SerializeObject
            (_context.Candidator.Select(ca => new { value = ca.Id, data = ca.Name }));

        return Json(new { suggestion = q });
    }
```

But i get this error in console and autocomplete not working:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

After serach i found out that i send bad json format. Now how can i send this format to view

```
{
    suggestions: [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the reference in github, when you return data from the controller, the field name is `suggestions` instead of `suggestion` . Also , if the fields(like Id and Name) you select contain `int` type values, you can convert them to `string` type, otherwise it will cause errors in the `jquery.autocomplete.js` file :

```
public IActionResult fetchCondidate()
{
    var q = _context.Candidator.Select(ca => new { value = ca.Id.ToString(), data = ca.Name.ToString() }).ToList();

    return Json(new { suggestions = q });
}
```

View :

```
$('#searchinput').autocomplete({
       serviceUrl: '/Controller/fetchCondidate',
       onSelect: function (suggestion) {
            alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
       },
});
```